# Difference between array and pointer types in llvm

Tags: llvm

For example, if I have the following struct

```
%struct.foo_struct = type { [3 x i32], i16*, i32}
```

Let's say we have a pointer `%struct.foo_struct* %P`.

I know I can do `%tmp0 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.foo_struct, %struct.foo_struct* %P, i64 0, i32 0, i64 2` to get the third element in the i32 array of the struct (the first element in the struct), but can I do `%tmp1 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.foo_struct, %struct.foo_struct* %P, i64 0, i32 1, i64 2` to get the third element in the i16 array of the struct (the second element in the struct), assuming that the i16 array has at least third elements?

I did not find any posts online discussing the difference between these two types, so can I assume they are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Simple reason being that the GEP instruction *never dereferences pointers*.

In

```
%tmp1 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.foo_struct, %struct.foo_struct* %P, i64 0, i32 1, i64 2
```

`i32 1` refers to the `i16*` pointer, which we can call `ptr`. Now `i64 2`  would refer to `*(ptr + 2)` which is illegal as it effectively tries to dereference `ptr`, which GEP isn't fond of doing.

If the first element of the struct was of type `[3 x i32]*`, you'd have the same trouble. See https://godbolt.org/z/ch9hGs and notice how a load instruction is always needed for struct members that are pointers.

Also if you had an `i32*` pointer and a `[n x i32]` array, the only real difference is you can always tell the size of the latter, but not the former.

Comment: Can I understand your last sentence as follows: `i32*` and `[n x i32]` are semantically the same (assuming `i32*` points to an array of size `n` so no memory overwrite occurs), but because we cannot try to deference pointers within the GEP instruction, we have to first load the pointer and perform the pointer addition using a second GEP?

Comment: And do you mean `i32 1` refers to the `i16*` pointer?

Comment: yup.. that was a typo

Comment: wrt to your first comment... Exactly

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot, because the second element of the array doesn't have three entries. It has precisely one.

A pointer type is a pointer to something; an instance of it occupies as much memory as a pointer does. An array is n somethings; an instance occupies n times as much memory as that something.

Assuming a 32-bit platform with zero padding:

If you were to bitcast so as to treat that i16* as an array and write to the third or fourth entry, you would overwrite the i32, because the i16* occupies as much memory as a pointer. On a 32-bit platforms a two-entry i16 array is as big as a pointer so the third and fourth entry would overlap the i32, and writing to the fifth entry or later writes beyond the struct's end.